# How to Get the Last Value in a Column WITH Filter on

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a List of names and want the last Name from the Column M.
The List starts at Row 12. My Formula works well:

```
=INDEX(M12:M;COUNTA(M12:M))
```

But if I use the Filter and the last name in the list is not visible anymore, I always get the last from the whole list, not from the Displayed List.

As example (Filter ON):

**M12: Name1 (visible)**

**M13: Name2 (visible)**

**M14: Name3 (not visible)**

With my formula, I Always get “Name3”, but I want “Name2”.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that easy. A workaround I've thinked of is to have an auxiliary column that sets the number of rows:

```
=INDEX(IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A),"")
```

Change A:A with the Column you wish, possibly M with work well. This is the column more to the right in my example:

[image]

Then when that column is filtered with your selections, will remain the row numbers shown and hidden. Then you can use SUBTOTAL, that has an option to perform different operations considering or not hidden values. With code 104 you can find the maximum of that auxiliary column without considering the hidden values:

=SUBTOTAL(104,D:D)

And use that value as the indicator of the row instead of COUNTA:

```
=INDEX(C:C,SUBTOTAL(104,D:D))
```

Check in E1 your formula and mine in E2 without filters:

[image]

And with filters:

[image]

Adapt the ranges and it should work